How can I scrape the titles from each row of a table with gibberish elements?
I'm trying to scrape the tabular content from this webpage using the requests module and the BeautifulSoup library.
I've managed to get the HTML elements containing the table having some gibberish content from the url I found in the dev tool, but still, I can't parse the content of that table as it is still full of \t,\n, e.t.c.
I wish to get the bold lettered text, as in FEIJAO CARIOCA URBAN from each row.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

start_url = 'http://nfe.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfeweb/sites/nfce/d/danfeNFCe?p=52240345543915002478650110004179799060499506|2|1|19|118.42|2b4937755a5a76797a522b6435534159784f5859427646356c7a4d3d|1|A763ED574AF1AECE3380D1E3A1EE188E3E95B414'
url = "http://nfe.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfeweb/sites/nfce/render/danfeNFCe?chNFe=52240345543915002478650110004179799060499506"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0",
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    s.get(start_url)
    resp = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
    tabular_content = soup.select_one("script[type='text/javascript']:-soup-contains('new DanfeNFCe')").contents[0]
    items = re.findall(r"\'(<div.*div>)\'",tabular_content)[0]
    print(items)

A glimpse of the table is more like this:
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t,\n            \t\t\t\t\t\t\tGO\n         <\/div>\n      <\/div>\n      <table border=\"0\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" id=\"tabResult\" data-filter=\"true\">\n         <tr id=\"Item + 1\">\n            <td valign=\"top\"><span class=\"txtTit\">FEIJAO CARIOCA URBAN<\/span><span class=\"RCod\">\n                  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(C\u00F3digo:\n                  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t3352048\n                  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n                  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/span><br><span class=\"Rqtd\"><strong>Qtde.:<\/strong>2<\/span><span class=\"RUN\"><strong>UN: <\/strong>un<\/span><span class=\"RvlUnit\"><strong>Vl. Unit.:<\/strong>\n                  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t&nbsp;\n                  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t7,99<\/span><\/td>\n            <td align=\"right\" valign=\"top\" class=\"txtTit noWrap\">\n               \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tVl. Total\n               \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<br><span class=\"valor\">15,98<\/span><\/td>\n         <\/tr>\n         <tr id=\"Item + 2\">\n            <td valign=\"top\"><span class=\"txtTit\">AZEITONA VDE S CAR<\/span><span class=\"RCod\">\n                  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(C\u00F3digo:\n                  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t5881927\n                  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n                  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/span><br><span class=\"Rqtd\"><strong>Qtde.:<\/strong>1<\/span><span class=\"RUN\"><strong>UN: <\/strong>un<\/span><span class=\"RvlUnit\"><strong>Vl. Unit.:<\/strong>\n                  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t&nbsp;\n                  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t5,59<\/span><\/td>


Have you considered grabbing the JSON file and parsing the HTML that is provided with this: http://nfe.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfeweb/sites/nfce/render/html/danfeNFCe?chNFe=52240345543915002478650110004179799060499506

Okay, that solves the issue. I really should have looked for the URL to the JSON content within the page source first. You can use this comment as an answer to the question. Thanks @Mark.

Okay, I've found success sticking with the approach I've started with. What @Mark suggested in the comment is the better way, though.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

start_url = 'http://nfe.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfeweb/sites/nfce/d/danfeNFCe?p=52240345543915002478650110004179799060499506|2|1|19|118.42|2b4937755a5a76797a522b6435534159784f5859427646356c7a4d3d|1|A763ED574AF1AECE3380D1E3A1EE188E3E95B414'
url = "http://nfe.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfeweb/sites/nfce/render/danfeNFCe?chNFe=52240345543915002478650110004179799060499506"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0",
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    s.get(start_url)
    resp = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
    tabular_content = soup.select_one("script[type='text/javascript']:-soup-contains('new DanfeNFCe')").contents[0]
    items = re.findall(r"(<table.*table>)",tabular_content)[0]
    cleaned_text = re.sub(r'\\r|\\n|\\', '', items)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(cleaned_text,"html.parser")
    for item in soup.select("table#tabResult > tr > td > span.txtTit"):
        print(item.get_text(strip=True))

Output:
FEIJAO CARIOCA URBAN
AZEITONA VDE S CAR
REFRES EM PO MID MAR
MARGARINA CLAYBOM C
ARROZ TP1 GAROTINHO
REFRES PO FRISCO ABA
REFRES PO FRISCO MOR
REFRES PO FRISCO LIM
REFRES PO FRISCO LAR
REFRES PO FRISCO LAR
PAPEL HIG FD PERSO V
PAO FRANCES CARREF K
MEXERICA PONKAN CRFO
CER DEVASSA LT 269ML
LIMAO TAHITI CRFO KG

